# How to loop through tables in python that come from a stored procedure in sql. With While Loop and Pyodbc?

Tags: python, sql, while-loop, pyodbc

```
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute("set nocount on exec SP") 
while(cur.nextset()):
    print(cur.description)
```

This code produces 10 tables, sometimes 11. I want to be able to use a while loop because the amount of tables might differ each time. The issue with this code above is it produces 9 tables instead of 10 because cur.nextset() runs and skips the first table.

What can I do to work around this? I want the code the work in a loop. I need a better function that works with the pyodbc module.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid skipping the first result set by moving your `nextset()` check to the bottom of the loop:

```python
cur.execute("set nocount on exec SP")
while True:
    # do stuff with the result set
    if not cur.nextset():
        break
print("All result sets have been processed.")
```

Comment: Brilliant because could not possibly be more concise.